# Login page using java swing in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jframe, login-page

I am making a Login page using java swing in netbeans. When I'm trying to click the "login" button, after entering the credentials, the next page is not visible. I used `NextPage().setVisible(true)` to do this. Should i use anything else?

Answer (score 2):

have you used actionListener() on the login page. use it to go to next page when login button is clicked and on the next page set it visible(true).

Answer (score 2):

You have to use new Nextpage().setVisible(True);

Answer (score 1):

This is how my login page gets data from the database

```
try{
    Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/restman","root","1234");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    String pq="select * from employeelogin";
    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(pq);
    String user=a1.getText();
    String psw=a2.getText();
    while(rs.next()){
        String uname=rs.getString("username");
        String password=rs.getString("password");
        if ((user.equals(uname))&&(psw.equals(password))) {
            new customerservice().setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            p1.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
} catch(Exception x) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,x.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: thank you for editing it.I am new here so I don't knew abt this.

Answer (score 0):

This is my piece of code. For login see from the last:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    Connection conn=null;
    try{
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
               Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        conn =DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();

        String S1 = jTextField1.getText();
        String S2 = jPasswordField1.getText().toString();
        String S3=jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        if(S1.isEmpty() || S1 == null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please insert a valid user name", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }
        // if password is blank, warning message shown
        if(S2.isEmpty() || S2 == null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password field is empty", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
        }

        int flag=0;
        String sql;
        sql="SELECT * from member where EMAIL='"+S1+"'";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        //System.out.println(rs.next());
        String uname="",pw="",category="";
        while(rs.next()){                       
            uname=rs.getString("EMAIL");
            pw=rs.getString("PASSWORD");
            category=rs.getString("CATEGORY");

            if(uname.matches(S1) && pw.equals(S2)==true && category.matches(S3))
            {
                flag=1;

                if(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()=="VISITOR")
                {
                    setVisible(false);
                    Newvisitor f1= new Newvisitor(S1);
                    f1.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.darkGray);
                    f1.setVisible(true);
                    // jButton6.setVisible(true);
                }
                else if(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()=="ACCOUNTANT")
                {
                    setVisible(false);
                    inter4 f=new inter4();
                    f.getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153,153,255));
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
                else if(jComboBox2.getSelectedItem()=="ADMINISTRATOR")
                {
                    setVisible(false);
                    Admin f2=new Admin();
                    f2.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.darkGray);
                    f2.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        } 
        if(flag==0)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"login failed");      
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException ss){
        ss.printStackTrace(); 
    }   `
}
```